# Does ROWLEX support SPARQL?

Tags: rowlex

Does ROWLEX support SPARQL?
Does ROWLEX support SQL Server?
Does ROWLEX act lik Joseki server?
Where can I find more detail information regarding ROWLEX besides http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/HowToUse.aspx?
Thank you in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Responses below are valid for ROWLEX 2.1. Later versions may deviate from these.

**SPARQL support?** No
**SQL Server support?** No
**ROWLEX works like JOSEKI?** 
Not at all, ROWLEX is not a triple store with a SPARQL end point! Using ROWLEX, you can browse or modify RDF graphs in an object-oriented style by pulling them *transiently into memory*. Due to this fact,

- you should not handle gigantic chunks at once,
- do not consider persistence as for a DB. Your graphs can be read from/dumped into static RDF text file or .NET string

Consider the following use case scenario with ROWLEX:

1. You store your zillions of triples in JOSEKI or any other RDF store you like.
2. You fire a SPARQL query to your store, and get back an RDF graph
3. Instead of analyzing/changing the triples of the result manually, you load the result into ROWLEX and you can do that in an object oriented style.
4. If you modified the graph, you can post it back to your store by SPARQL Update.

**More info**: Here! Sorry for the slow response, I was out of office.